# How to add ExtensionDelegate to watchOS 1 to 2 upgrade?

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, watchos-2, watchos

I'm upgrading my watchOS 1 app to watchOS 2 and noticed there's a `ExtensionDelegate` class in new watchOS 2 targets. I tried adding this file to my watchOS 1 app (after updating the deployment version), but it's not hitting the break point in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Here's what my class looks like:

```
import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // Perform any final initialization of your application.
        print("applicationDidFinishLaunching for watchOS")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
    }

}
```

Is there more to just adding the file, or did I not upgrade properly?

Answer (score 2):

There's **a lot more** that changes, than just adding that file.

What you should do is target your project, then choose Editor -> Validate Settings.

- This will validate your project and determine if anything needs to be updated.  As a part of that process, it will offer to upgrade your project settings from watchOS 1 to watchOS 2.

[image]

The number of changes made are too extensive to list individually; I wouldn't recommend trying to manually upgrade your project.

**An alternate approach**

You could backup your watchOS 1 files, delete the two watchOS 1 targets within your Xcode project, then select Editor -> Add target.  Select watchOS, Application, then WatchKit App.

[image]

This will configure the necessary targets and settings for watchOS 2.

You could then add your source code back to the project, but you'd still have to transition your code to watchOS 2 to account for changes such as migrating from shared app groups to using Watch Connectivity.

**Update:**

Simply adding that file is not enough. Apple determines details about the extension via plist preferences and project settings.  If your watch app extension isn't called, something likely didn't get changed correctly.  Perhaps it's still running as a watchKit 1 app extension on the phone, instead of using the extension in the watch app bundle?

If you want to *try* to fix it by hand, here are a couple of things you could check:

- Make sure the WatchKit extension Info.plist contains

  ```
  <key>WKExtensionDelegateClassName</key>
      <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate</string>
  ```
- Make sure the `project.pbxproj` Watch App and Watch Extension product types were changed to include a **2**.

  ```
  productType = "com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2";
  productType = "com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension";
  ```

There's **much more** that's changed than those few lines. It's possible other changes were missed, so you may want to delete the targets and start with an empty watch project, **to be certain** that everything is properly set up.  Otherwise, it's trial-and-error discovering what else might not have gotten properly changed.

*As an aside, since you ran into problems, you should [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and include your watchKit 1 app, so Apple can fix that Xcode issue.*

Comment: I did let Xcode upgrade it for me, but it never added the ExtensionDelegate. Can I add that myself?

Comment: It's not enough to merely add the file.  If some critical setting didn't get updated, the system won't know to call the code in that added file. Your best bet is to create new (watchKit 2) targets.

Comment: The problem was in the Info.plist this was missing: `<key>WKExtensionDelegateClassName</key><string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate</string>`. It's sometimes more dangerous to delete/recreate because of legacy dependency settings that would need to be recreate (more work than it seems).

Comment: The `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)` part of `WKExtensionDelegateClassName` did it for me. I was trying to use only `ExtensionDelegate` and it wasn't working. Thanks!